# Copy-paste data frame from Rstudio Viewer to Excel not working since update

Tags: r, excel, data.table, rstudio, copy-paste

I just installed the new version of R (4.0.3) and Rstudio (Version 1.3.1093) on Windows, and I cannot copy-paste from the viewer to excel anymore.

Here is the details:

1)View data table in the Rstudio viewer:

```
library(data.table)
View(data.table(A = c(1:10), B = c(11:20)))
```

2)Copy the selection:

[image]

3)Paste in excel (CTRL + V or Right click + Paste + Keep Source Formatting (K))

[image]

As you can see it doesn't work and only paste an blank cell.

The details of my R version:

```
version
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

Comment: Why not just use `write.csv()`?

Comment: This might be better at theRStudio topic in the [RStudio community forums](https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide/9) as it's most likely the issue is with the RStudio update.

Comment: @Phil: sometimes it's faster to quickly copy-paste during the development phase. In most cases I use fwrite

Comment: To each their own, but I'm not sure how anyone in the SO community can fix this.I would just file an issue in their GH repo.

Comment: I also asked in the SO community but nobody had an answer and it was closed after 90 days.